# Как сделать медленный скролл внутри блока?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Как сделать очень медленную прокрутку внутри блока?

```css
.datas {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datas">
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Подозреваю что js понадобится, но как такое реализовать никак не пойму.
Подскажите варианты на чистом js, а лучше на jquery чтобы меньше кода было

Answer (score 3):

Нашел решение, вроде работает как надо

```js
document.querySelector('.datas').addEventListener('wheel', function(ev) {
  ev = window.event || ev;
  let delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (ev.wheelDelta || -ev.detail)));
  this.scrollTop -= (delta * 2); // количество пикселей = 2
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.datas {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="datas">
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать плагин [Nicescroll](https://nicescroll.areaaperta.com/demo/)

```js
$(function() {  
    $(".datas").niceScroll({
     scrollspeed: 5,
     mousescrollstep: 5
    });
});
```

```css
.datas {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.7.6/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<div class="datas">
  <table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```